# why isn't there any space at the ends for child elements of this flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was following a tutorial to make a website, and in a particular section we had to make a flexbox container with three child elements. I have checked and re-checked my code, it is the same as the video but there isn't any space at the right and left end of the flex container. Why isn't is working? (I've given the CSS code below)

[image]

```
.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-col {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: #fff3f3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* this is the title of the child elements*/
 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.course-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

This is the HTML code :

```
<!--  COURSES  !-->

    <section class="course">
      <h1>Courses We Offer</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="course-col">
            <h3>Intermediate</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course-col">
          <h3>Degree</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course-col">
          <h3>Post Graduation</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: ok, adding it right away

Comment: Moreover, you can add margin to the container

Comment: okay, let me try that

Comment: for some reason, adding margin isn't making a difference

Comment: Take a look at the code that I add. The margin work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try only this:

```
.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;/* here */
}
```

Also:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto 10px; /* here */
  }
}
```

Comment: trying that out

Comment: @fatima_r24 div(.row) not closed!! fix it and try justify-content: space-around;

Comment: space-around works, but when I turn on responsive mode, the same problem's happening

Comment: @fatima_r24 Thank you:) in this case in the responsive mode: {flex-direction: column; margin: auto 10px;}

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
margin:10px;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-col {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: #fff3f3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding: 20px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* this is the title of the child elements*/
 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.course-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
This is the HTML code :

<!--  COURSES  !-->
```

```html
    <section class="course">
      <h1>Courses We Offer</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="course-col">
            <h3>Intermediate</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course-col">
          <h3>Degree</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="course-col">
          <h3>Post Graduation</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Solving a problem with a "*" CSS selector is a bad idea : it will impact all your code AND it doesn't help to understand which element need margins.

Comment: @See OX could you suggest something then?

Comment: Why not? the section needs margin. it is the container.

Comment: I just saw, trying that out

Comment: @YarinLevi the universal CSS selector "*" used alone will applied the properties to all elements on your webpage. It seems to me, that it is over use here. The question's author needed one element to have a specified margin, not all elements to have all margin.  

Universal CSS selector doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors